# Why can I not get ahold of HR to followup on an internship application status?

Tags: internship, human-resources, europe

I have tried on multiple occasions to call the Human Resources department regarding my internship applications, only to be continuously (total of three phone calls over two days) turned down at the first person I speak to (receptionist, never get through to HR). I only seem to have some success when I have names and I don't mention it's about an internship.

- The *entire* HR department happens to be at a meeting.
- The is *nobody* available right now, call back in 30 minutes.
- They have *already* gone home for the day (at 15:45).

(Repeatedly and in that sequence)

**Is there some 'thing' here I am missing? I'm being lead around in circles as opposed to getting a 'no, we don't do phone calls unless scheduled'. Most internship materials suggest you follow up after two weeks to show your interest, but I can't get past the reception - why might this be the case? I know no one can know specifically, but it seems strange to me.**

Today I managed to talk sufficiently long to the receptionist that I should call at 08:00 in the morning. As much as I know that NASA called astronaut candidates with random questions at 04:00 to see if they were 'helpful' as opposed to 'annoyed and grumpy', is what I am seeing some test in persistence and interest towards the employer, or do they just not take these cold calls throughout the day to be able to work?

*Field: Engineering, Europe.*

Comment: Have you tried emailing the person in charge of the internship recruitment? How long has it been since you applied?

Comment: @Brandin generally only mentions a general email with no names available. Waited ~2 weeks.

Comment: On a scale of 1-10 in importance to HR, hiring interns is a 1-3. They do much more than hire and, even in hiring, permanent employees are far more important to them. 2 weeks is nothing to wait for an internship decision. I assure you that if they are interested, they will contact you. Move on and keep applying rather than spin your wheels making annoying phone calls.

Comment: *"I have tried on multiple occasions to call the Human Resources department regarding my internship applications,"* **There's your problem** Aside from the fact that you don't ever call for stuff like this any more, you can get away with contacting HR to request an update **once** between interviews/decisions and then only after a considerable amount of time has passed since the last contact with the company (weeks, not days, let alone hours).

Comment: Hi Mike, I made an edit to this to make it more generic and more easily answerable in a general sense. It was picking up some close votes and hopefully this makes it more on topic here. No one can know in your specific case why (except their HR) but there are definitely some good and more common reasons for this.

Comment: Sadly very common practice, in my experience, for "human" resources departments to omit the "human" element altogether. Regardless of the fact that OP was probably just annoying them, basic human decency says that instead of dicking someone around (and forcing them to call back because they are massively confused, wasting even more company time), take 3 minutes to explain the situation to them. This behaviour (you being dicked around by everyone) would likely continue if you were to be taken on as an intern (especially since you're the intern). If this bothers you - run and don't look back.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

No there's not a plot. Cold calling is bound to be annoying to them and not likely to receive results.

Reasons it's not likely to receive results is:

- **It's annoying.** HR has a defined application process and you are trying to bypass it. At best you get a "we'll get back to you when we process your application" and at worst you annoy people. You've already tried "multiple times" - this is going to annoy anyone who receives your calls!
- **Internships are not that important**. Everyone has a lot more important things to do almost assuredly. Super important to you, not at all important to them.
- **HR lives in meetings.** When I have viewed HR calendars at my work, they are filled with meetings. It's not surprising to me they would be in meetings
- **Bypassing a process normally doesn't work**. Unless you know someone who can move the process along internally, all you do is annoy people. Your application probably included how they would get back to you as an auto-reply email (or something similar).
- **They probably have dozens of applications.** The more desirable the company the more people who likely applied.
- **They may want to interview other candidates first, but not reject you immediately.** If they have lots of good candidates they may not want to immediately reject someone. If their top candidates don't succeed in the interview and/or accept offers, they may want to follow up with someone.

Also, the reality is, many times when you don't get a job you don't get any notification at all.

Annoying HR almost assuredly won't change a rejection. But it might annoy someone enough to drop your chances if you were in the process.

---

Also some anecdotal stories - I've not heard back regarding internships for *months* before getting a "hey are you still available?" call a week before I started a different internship.

In some cases I've received auto-generated rejection emails *years* later for jobs I didn't remember applying to!

Comment: It's interesting to see the pretty negative perception of phone calls in response to my question. I actually don't like doing it myself, but most manuals/guides/advice I've read suggest following up after around two weeks to keep it 'current' or 'on top'. I guess that also stops working after some time when everybody does it...

Comment: @MikeFoxtrot keep in mind there is a big difference between a single followup and "multiple occasions" and "continuously turned down." There is also a difference between interview followup and application followup. In one case, you know the company wanted to consider you - in the other, you have no idea (companies won't interview 100 people for a single position normally but may get that many applicants, etc).

Comment: We had over 900 applications for one job opening we had (and that was after HR got done filtering out the totally unqualified). So of course we did not take the time to talk to every one and I am sure HR did not either.

Comment: @HLGEM I see absolutely no reason why I company can not sent ~890 reject emails or letters. It is common courtesy to do so and I find it highly unprofessional if companies don't do it. This just sucks for the applicant, who never knows that he or she got rejected and also increases workload for HR, as at least some people will call or email to get a follow up. It doesn't make any sense to not notify people. Of course, it should be an highly-individual 30 minute phone talk for everyone...

Comment: I'm not sure the "multiple times" point is that relevant here. It doesn't sound like any of those attempts actually managed to connect with somebody in HR. If OP had received an answer of "we're sorry but we can't discuss that at this time", then it would certainly be poor etiquette to keep calling. If every call results in "no one from HR is available" then it would make sense to call back at another time and try again.

Comment: @ChrisHayes if they wanted to get back to him in a serious sense, someone would have asked, "sure, what is your name? I'll have [HR person] give you a call later today" rather than deflecting him.

Comment: @ChrisHayes you are very correct actually. It stopped at the receptionist, never got through to HR. They asked me what my reason for calling was presumably to check I was not an existing employee or something. In such a short chat, there is no way they could have noted down my (real) name and evaluated my importance. I also perhaps exaggerated on 'continuously': I've called two companies each a total of three times over the past two days, and been told to call back later each time, as opposed to just getting a 'no'...

Comment: `Bypassing a process normally doesn't work.` You kidding?  The squeaky wheel gets the grease!  *If you can pull it off,* finding a way to bypass gatekeepers and talk directly to a decision maker is the most effective way to accomplish just about anything where bureaucracy is involved.

Comment: @MasonWheeler The squeaky wheel only gets the grease if it's an important wheel. If it's an unimportant wheel, it gets dumped in the garage with all the other annoying, unimportant things that don't work properly.

Comment: @DavidRicherby \*shrug\* It's always worked for me, and I make no particular claim of importance...

Comment: @MasonWheeler it depends on the context. If you are blindly submitting an application and don't have the hiring manager details, you have _already_ lost the ability to easily grease the squeaky wheel. Alternatively, if you meet a hiring manager who encourages you to apply, then they will be more than eager to help you bypass HR (I don't think many hiring managers really like working with HR, either). But that assumes you have already made the meaningful connection - in those cases, go for it!

Comment: @enderland: You know how I got my first programming job?  I saw an ad online looking for developers.  I knew the technology they were using.  It encouraged people to apply on their website, but I looked the company up and found they were only about 20 miles away.  About an hour later I walked into their office and asked about the job.  That got me an interview with the development team leader, because it was a branch office (HR was all at Corporate) and The Boss was away.  I did well enough on that to get an interview with The Boss when he got back, and he made me a job offer.

Comment: If I had gone through "the system", I would almost certainly have been filtered out before ever reaching someone qualified to evaluate whether or not I was actually a competent programmer, because I didn't have previous work experience.

Comment: @Dirrk, I live in the real world where virtually no company sends out these letters and no one with experience expects them.  It is just the way the world works. No sense whining about it. When you are in charge of the world, you can change that.

Answer (score 33):

These people are what is known as gatekeepers. It's very easy to tell them not to forward calls from people we don't want to talk to.

Right now, your internship is probably the number one thing on your mind and it is about 1000th on an HR departments. There's no shortage of candidates. They don't make the company any money. And you're not around long enough to cause any major harm if you're a bad hire.

You're going to be on the other end some day. I hope you have the time to take calls from job/internship candidates, but don't count on it.

Comment: If they didn't do a bad job, they wouldn't need to answer calls.

Comment: @davor, they are not necessaarily doing a bad job, they don't have to work on your schedule and take your application as the most important thing in the world.  They do have other much more important task to do most of the time.

Comment: @HLGEM not sending rejection emails is a bad job. It's worse than that actually, it's quite rude and disrespectful.

Comment: @Davor, In over 30 years in the world world I have exactly once gotten a letter saying I was not selected for a job I applied for (and that was one I interviewed for). It is not a common practice.  It is not rude; it is the norm.

Comment: @HLGEM - I've only ever applied to like 3 jobs where I was rejected, and I've always received a rejection email, including from MS for an internship. And it doesn't matter if it's the norm or common practice, it's still rude. You're setting up a false dilemma.

Answer (score 1):

### Because they don't want you to contact them

The answer to the literal question of "Why can I not get ahold of HR to followup on an internship application status?" is that they have explicitly taken steps to prevent you from getting ahold of them to followup on an internship application status. You're likely getting such responses from receptionists because they're doing their job in protecting other employees from undesired contact attempts - you may think of them as a 'meatspace spam filter'.

Companies who have a small number of applicants may choose to treat each application individually.

Companies who have a large amount of applicants may (and often do) choose to implement a process that minimizes time spent on each individual application. For example, for a vacancy with 100 or 300 applicants (common in some industries), you would generally want to spend any meaningful time on only a limited amount of them - you'd have a first stage screening process that would leave you with a manageable amount of candidates (10-20) and take something like a minute per application. 5 minutes per application times 100-300 applications would mean 8-24 working hours for just an initial screening - so that's generally not aceptable.

Throwing out good candidates for random reasons at this stage is okay (because there are more than 10-20 good candidates, and even a perfect screening process will have to eliminate many good candidates w/o consideration); wasting time on individual phone followup is not resonable - they will spend time on the candidates they selected, the rest will get an automated response if the system allows to do that in an efficient way (i.e., no personalized responses or explanations).

This applies for *advertised vacancies* - cold calling / cold mailing for internship opportunities may often deliberately mean no response at all, ever, and an automatic forward to the trash bin. They're likely not interested in applications, and even less interested in spending time to discuss them.